# Is there any physical quantity which is derived from vector triple product?

Tags: vectors

Work done is derived by scalar triple product of, for example when in case of Torque. $W=\int{dθ.(r×F)}$. But is there any example of vector triple product which results in a physical quantity used in Physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The torque on a charged particle accelerated in a magnetic field is given by
$${\bf \tau}=q{\bf r} \times ({\bf v}\times {\bf B})\ .$$

Centrifugal force can be written as
$${\bf F} = -m{\bf \omega}\times({\bf \omega}\times {\bf r})\ .$$

Comment: You might say that B itself is a cross product of the vector potential

Comment: Wow interesting. Finally something that needs Vector Triple Product.